# multer + socket.io + FormData sending file issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io, multer

I'm trying to make sending pictures with socket.io and bumped into this error

> return req.headers['transfer-encoding'] !== undefined ||
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'transfer-encoding' of undefined

Before I used axios + multer, it worked perfect

So there is my code

server:

```
const fileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  originalname: String,
  filename: String,
  path: String,
  mimetype: String,
});

const File = mongoose.model("File", fileSchema);
socket.on("ROOM:FILE_UPLOAD", (formData) => {
    upload.single("image")(formData, null, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else {
        const originalname = formData.originalname;
        const filename = formData.filename;
        const path = formData.path;
        const mimetype = formData.mimetype;

        const file = new File({
          originalname,
          filename,
          path,
          mimetype,
        });

        file.save((err, image) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            console.log(`Image saved to MongoDB: ${image._id}`);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

client:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
function handleFileSelect(event: any) {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  }
function sendMsg(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", file);
    socket.emit("ROOM:FILE_UPLOAD", formData);
  }

return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={upload}>
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={handleFileSelect}
            name="image"
          />
          <button onClick={sendMsg}>send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

where I made mistake ?

Comment: Where is the line starting with `return req.headers['transfer-encoding']`? I can't see it in your question.

Comment: @jabaa the main reason, why I ask, i'm trying to return anything, i'm just trying to send picture from client to server with sockets

Comment: @jabaa I added lines of code where MIGHT be an error, at the top of server code

Comment: Where is the line starting with `return req.headers['transfer-encoding']`?

Comment: @jabaa it's in node_modules /home/galich/Desktop/freelance/gambling-chat/server/node_modules/type-is/index.js:93
  return req.headers['transfer-encoding'] !== undefined ||

Comment: Can you start the server with your debugger and find out which line of your code causes this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251409/discussion-between-daniil-galitskii-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was a bad idea from start to send pictures as message via sockets, it would be big server load, so I would use another algorithm similar to telegram
there is the [link](https://core.telegram.org/api/files) on docs. There is no any reason to try fix this error because the main mistake was decision how to send pictures in chat